# AngularFire shows user object as null

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I've got an AngularFire app and I'm trying to access the user object that is returned with the $firebaseSimpleLogin factory. Here's the code:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://[myfirebase].firebaseio.com');
var loginObj = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);
var user = loginObj.user;
```

When I console.log the loginObj it shows that the user property is indeed an object with all the information I need but the user variable somehow becomes null. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The user object will be null until you actually log the user in. You can do so using the `$login` method, for example:

```js
loginObj.$login('facebook');
```

If the login succeeds, `loginObj` will be updated and the `user` property should point to the logged in user.